# Online API for querying Microsoft Defender's latest antivirus pattern version?

Tags: powershell, windows-defender

Is there an online API from Microsoft where I can query what version the newest available AV pattern file is - so it can be compared with the locally installed pattern version?

With Powershell, for the locally installed versions, I use:

```
Get-MpComputerStatus | select AntivirusSignatureVersion
```

**What I am looking for**

Something similar (can also be a REST api - anything) to retrieve the most current versions available at Microsoft.

The version info for the newest antivirus pattern is available on the below website - but I don't want to parse the HTML - as this can change any time.

[Defender Pattern info](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/defenderupdates)

Comment: the parentheses and select are redundant. You just need `(Get-MpComputerStatus).AntivirusSignatureVersion` or `Get-MpComputerStatus | select AntivirusSignatureVersion`

Comment: Thanks for this input - corrected. But do you also have a solution for my question?